# Android Studio: Project location contains whitespace in user folder. How do I change my user folder name

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I recently installed Android Studio 2.2.3 but when I try to create a project it gives me a message saying that my project location contains whitespace.

Here is my project location: `C:\Users\Ziyaad B\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication`.

I tried moving all Android Studio files to `C:\Android` but it won't delete or be removed from `C:\Users\Ziyaad B\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication`.

Is there any way that I can possibly change that user folder to not have a space?

Comment: You would be able to create and move your folder  if 1) You're an administrator 2) no other process has that folder open

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the space like C:\Users\Ziyaad B... to C:\Users\ZiyaadB... . Then in Android Studio and go to File>Open. Now select the location where your project is stored. Also, next time it automatically pick that location.

Comment: I don't think you can just rename a Windows user folder

Comment: After rename, you need to open that projects again. Hence, android studio saves location automatically.

Comment: But you can't rename your user folder while logged in to it

Comment: Obviously, you need to restart android studio.

Comment: Again, I think you're missing the question